# How to present mobile view on desktop as it is?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, frontend

I have developed a vue.js site for mobile devices. I have written front end design in bootstrap only for mobile view, without making it responsive for desktops. I want to show the same mobile view on desktops as well. How to do that?

[image: Want to achieve something like this]

Comment: You can try embedding the website to an iframe with a smaller width?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a column to get that shape, you can use the class `.col-8` instead of `.col-md-8` to, for example, have a column width of 8 at all sizes instead of just medium and larger.

You could also set a `max-width` in the CSS for your `<body>` or `.container`, so the page can't get wider than whatever you specify.